# Unable to get button in Google Maps infowindow to push to router

Tags: google-maps, vue.js, vue-router

I am using the Google Maps infowindow to display the address of the map pin along with a button to navigate to the detail page.  I can get an alert to display but when I try and use $router.push to navigate, nothing happens, there are no errors in the console.  How do I get this to work?

```
    const descInfo =
      '<div id="iw-container"><b>' +
      terminal.name +
      ' ' +
      metadata.type +
      '</b><br>' +
      terminal.street +
      '<br>' +
      terminal.city +
      ', ' +
      terminal.state +
      '. ' +
      terminal.zip_code +
      '<br><br>' +
      `<button @click="$router.push('/my-apps/terminals/${terminal.id}')">View</button>` +
      '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears that Nuxt was the issue. This appears to work as expected.

```
`<button onclick="$nuxt._router.push('/my-apps/terminals/${terminal.id}')">View</button>`
```